# help in parsing

Tags: perl, design-patterns, matching

I am having a XML file as shown below,

```
<message1>
<val1>100</val1>
<val2>200</val2>
<val3>300</val3>
<val4>400</val4>
</message1>

<message2>
<val1>100</val1>
<val2>200</val2>
<val3>300</val3>
<val4>400</val4>
</message2>
```

I have to parse the values (val) and i could not use XML::Simple module. The parsing should be started from `<message1>` and i have to put the values in an array till `</message1>` and then i have to repeat this for `<message2>` till `</message2>`.

Pictorially it is like

```
<message1>
   ----100
   ----200
   ----300
   ----400
</message1>

<message2>
   ----100
   ----200
   ----300
   ----400
</message2>
```

Can any one help me .. I am struggling a lot

Thanks

Senthil kumar

Comment: That isn't an XML file. An XML file has exactly one root element.

Comment: Can we assume you're also using Perl? That was the first result I got for XML::Simple module...

Comment: i am using regex (perl) and i could not use any perl xml modules

Comment: Then you are on a path of utter futility.

Comment: Is the only reason you can't use built in libraries because there are multiple root elements?  If so, why not just surround your entire text with a dummy root element?

Comment: @bobince: nonsense.  why do you say that?

Comment: Why can't you use XML::Simple?  Regex is absolutely the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: @ysth: because regex is inherently, on a basic design level, incapable of parsing XML or any other markup scheme of similar complexity. If you know the exact output a particular script is going to produce, so you don't have to cope with all possible XML constructs, you can sometimes get away with it, but even so you are crafting a more fragile and buggy solution that if you just used an XML parser that was designed for the job. Every modern language has proper XML parsing available. Don't futz with regex.

Comment: @bobince: ah, I wasn't sure if you meant the path of utter futility was using regex, using perl, or using regexes to parse xml.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're back in 1999, I think I would forget about strict and warnings, use symbolic references and string eval, and be done with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while( <DATA>)
  { s{<(message\d)>}{\@$1=(}; # @message1=(
    s{<val\d>}{};             #
    s{<\/val\d>}{,};          #                ,
    s{</message\d>}{);};      #                 );
    $s.=$_;
  };

eval $s;

$,= ", "; $\= "\n";
foreach (1..2) { print "\@message$_: ", @{"message$_"}; }



__DATA__
<message1>
<val1>100</val1>
<val2>200</val2>
<val3>300</val3>
<val4>400</val4>
</message1>

<message2>
<val1>100</val1>
<val2>200</val2>
<val3>300</val3>
<val4>400</val4>
</message2>
```

(in case that's not clear: that's a joke! As they say "Have you tried using an XML parser instead?")

Comment: @ysth: you're right, I removed it. I also removed the my declaration, sorry, good habits die hard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is completely regular as you show, the following should work.
But you are far better off getting a real XML parser to work, by wrapping a root element around all your content or by parsing each message separately.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
while (<>) {
    # skip blank lines
    next unless /\S/;

    my ($tag) = /^<(.*)>$/
        or warn("expected tag, got $_ "), next;
    $data{$tag} ||= [];

    while (<>) {
        last if /^<\/\Q$tag\E>$/;

        my (undef, $value) = /^<val(\d+)>(.*)<\/val\1>$/
            or warn("expected val, got $_ "), next;
        push @{ $data{$tag} }, $value;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%data;
```